# Bar chart in excel makes the difference look higher than it actually is

Tags: excel, charts

The blue bar indicates how much something should be, the orange bar shows how much there actually is. The difference in number is only 7 however the chart makes it look like the difference is more than 1/2. How can I change this to the bar chart looks more accurate to a difference of 7 and not 1/2.

[image]

Comment: Change the y-axis to start at 0.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/change-the-scale-of-the-vertical-value-axis-in-a-chart-05973661-e56a-4486-a9f3-f9ce41df0021

Answer (score 0):

Double click on y axis. The format axis tab will appear and in the axis options change the minimum limit to zero.